# Google maps custom marker not loading the firebase images

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

I am developing an Android Studio app using Java. My app allows a user to sign in and view custom markers on a map with custom markers. When a user click on a custom marker they get taken to another activity.

My problem is, When accessing this activity via the custom marker, the app does not load the images stored in firebase.

Any Suggestions on what the problem might be? Thanks.

```
map activity that deals with the markers:

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener
(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.getTitle().equals("Mario's Italian"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MapView.this, 
                ItalianMenu.class));
            if (marker.getTitle().equals("Bamboo Tandoori"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MapView.this, 
                IndianMenu.class));
            if (marker.getTitle().equals("King Chinese 
            Takeaway"))
                startActivity(new Intent(MapView.this, 
                ChineseMenu.class));
            return false;
        }
    }); 



activity that opens up when a user clicks the marker:

package myapp.zerbu.partyloader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import myapp.zerbu.partyloader.Common.Common;
import myapp.zerbu.partyloader.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import myapp.zerbu.partyloader.Model.Category;
import myapp.zerbu.partyloader.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;

public class ItalianMenu extends AppCompatActivity
    implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference category;

TextView txtName;

RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Mario's Italian");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //Init Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    category = database.getReference("Category");

    //Basket
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)
 findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own 
action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new
 ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    //Set Name for user
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = 
    (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

    //Load menu
    recycler_menu = (RecyclerView) 
    findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadMenu();
}

private void loadMenu() {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> 
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,
 MenuViewHolder>(Category.class, 
R.layout.activity_italian_menu, MenuViewHolder.class, 
category) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder
 viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());

Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem = model;

            viewHolder.setImageClickListener(new 
    ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position,
     boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(ItalianMenu.this, 
    ""+clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar 
if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_restaurants) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_basket) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)
 findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: have you checked if you are really getting image from model.getImage() ?

Comment: show you firebase db structure

Comment: @uneq95 Yes. I have launched the app to load the ItalianMenu activity directly and the images load. It just doesn't load when I access it using the custom marker.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdcO8.png